# How to select parent of currently selected object?

Tags: unity

When i select an object, i can't find a function to select its parent. Does this basic feature exist ? I want to select the parent of selected object and then step up to find parent of parent so on without using the hierarchy window.

Comment: I don't think this is a 'bad' question - but you definitely should have googled this first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parent` property on the `GameObject`’s `transform`.

So given a `GameObject` called `player`, you can do

```
player.transform.parent
```

See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html for more.

Comment: I think the question is asking how to do that in the editor UI, not in a script.

Comment: Wait... if it's just the editor UI, can't you just use the left arrow key to jump to the parent?

Comment: I'm using mac version. and left arrow does not select the parent. And in top menu/edit , i can only find 'select children' (shift C) , but there's no select parent.

Comment: Thanks found the answer, there's no feature in unity to select parent. I have to use  'select parent' addon.